# Assign value to variable using CodeDOM in C#

Tags: c#, codedom

I have used CodeDOM to generate C# code but I'm not able to generate code for following line of statement.

```
string FileName=String.Empty;
FileName=Path.GetFileName(file1);
```

From above code I have written the code for first line using following snippet

```
using(CodeVariableDeclarationStatement strFileName = 
    new CodeVariableDeclarationStatement(typeof(string), "strFileName",
    new CodeTypeReferenceExpression("String.Empty"));)
```

but not able to add code for second line using codeDOM. So please let me know how can I achive it.

Comment: You have to use [`CodeAssignStatement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.codedom.codeassignstatement(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I have used CodeAssignStatement to generate following line of code.
CodeAssignStatement stat = new CodeAssignStatement(new CodeVariableReferenceExpression("VPath"), new CodeTypeReferenceExpression(new CodeTypeReference("VPath + \"\\\\\" + arr[arr.Length - 1]")));
But it replaced '+' with '.' in the generated code.So how can I resolve it.

Comment: @Pankaj Don't use `CodeTypeReference` if you're not going to reference a type. Also, that seems like a new question to me, so you should ask about that in a new question.

Comment: @xanatos It looks like your comment answered the question. Do you want to write it as an answer?

Answer (score 3):

```
// For the first line: string FileName = string.Empty;
var declareVariableFileName = new CodeVariableDeclarationStatement(                 // Declaring a variable.
    typeof(string),                                                                 // Type of variable to declare.
    "FileName",                                                                     // Name for the new variable.
    new CodePropertyReferenceExpression(                                            // Initialising with a property.
        new CodeTypeReferenceExpression(typeof(string)), "Empty"));                 // Identifying the property to invoke.

// For the second line: FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file1);
var assignGetFileName = new CodeAssignStatement(                                    // Assigning a value to a variable.
    new CodeVariableReferenceExpression("FileName"),                                // Identifying the variable to assign to.
    new CodeMethodInvokeExpression(                                                 // Assigning from a method return.
        new CodeMethodReferenceExpression(                                          // Identifying the class.
            new CodeTypeReferenceExpression(typeof(Path)),                          // Class to invoke method on.
            "GetFileName"),                                                         // Name of the method to invoke.
        new CodeExpression[] { new CodeVariableReferenceExpression("file1") }));    // Single parameter identifying a variable.

string sourceCode;

using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
{
    var csProvider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
    csProvider.GenerateCodeFromStatement(declareVariableFileName, writer, null);
    csProvider.GenerateCodeFromStatement(assignGetFileName, writer, null);

    sourceCode = writer.ToString();

    // sourceCode will now be...
    // string FileName = string.Empty;
    // FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file1);
}
```